# how to use Apache mod_proxy to provide access to Tomcat webapp

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have defined a Virtual Host for `example.com` in Tomcat Host Manager.

I can access `http://example.com:8080/Web_Application`. However I want to use `http://example.com/webapp`.

I also want to access `http://example.com/` through Apache for serving PHP+HTML. Only for `http://example.com/webapp` I want Tomcat to serve the Web Application on Port 8080.

Is it possible to hide the port number as well as map a url to a specific web application? What config changes are required to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard configuration.  You simply use `ProxyPass`, like this:

```
ProxyPass /webapp http://localhost:8080/Web_Application
ProxyPassReverse /webapp http://localhost:8080/Web_Application
```